# Bash script to compare two text files

Tags: bash, file

I'm trying to write a condition to compare two text files (simple "if [ file1 == file2 ]" doesn't work I think), I need to open those files, and then compare them.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you use built-in [`diff`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm) command like

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: `diff` is, in no way, a "built-in". Also `cmp` may be more appropriate here (but is often interchangeable for automated uses).

Comment: @EtanReisner, what I mostly meant is that something already existing but I knew it's built-in by seeing the man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html

Comment: That man page actually says that it *isn't* a built-in in any sense of the word. But it sounds like you meant "existing tool for this job" which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like the md5sum of the files and consider file with equal md5sum as equal. But please understand how hashfunctions work, e.g. see [Wikipedia article an cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).
Try it like this:

```
S1=$(md5sum test1.txt | cut -d \  -f 1)
S2=$(md5sum test2.txt | cut -d \  -f 1)
echo $S1
echo $S2
if [ "$S1" = "$S2" ]; then 
    echo "same" ; 
fi
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: @some-non-descript-user : According to the test-command man page e.g. at http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html a single `=` is ok.

Comment: OK. `test` surprises me again. ;-)

Comment: @some-non-descript-user Me too. And I admit that I looked into the man page before posting. There is a new form of test comand `[[ ... ]]`, which allows both `=` and `==`, see e.g. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression